# How to remove a string from a file in Ruby with user input?

Tags: ruby, file

I figured out how to search a file to locate a specific string based on user input, but I don't know how to delete said string once I've located it. I've seen various grep methods but don't know how to change those to input/output, so I've ended up with this:

```
puts "Enter media to delete";
characters = gets.chomp;

File.open("arraystarter.rb").each { |line| 
  unless characters.each_char.map  { |c| line.include?(c) }.include? false
    puts "Did you mean #{line}?";
  intent = gets.chomp.downcase
  case intent
  when 'yes'
  # TODO: Delete the line I've found
   puts "#{line} deleted!"
  when 'no'
  puts "Nevermind, then."
  end
  end
    }
```

I need to replace the puts/"deleted" line after when 'yes', but how?

Comment: You can't read and write to a file at the same time.  You'll have to read the file into an array for example, change that array, and write it back to the file (if the file is small).

Answer (score 1):

I've found apretty good solution to your question, it's a little complicated: it transforms the file into a string and then into an array, deletes the unwated line and then prints the array back to the file. I transformed your little piece of code, in a true script that finds how many lines contains the user input, and then asks you if you want to delete them all or just one of them. I took me a little to bring the code to this version, but I like challanges (maybe you laugh now, thinking "Challange? this?".... well for me it was a challange, due that I still have a lot to learn about Ruby). Hope It helps...

```
puts "Enter media to delete:"
characters = gets.chomp()
filename = "arraystarter.rb"
counts = 0

file_open = File.readlines(filename, 'rb')
file_to_string = file_open.map(&:inspect).join(',')
string = file_to_string.delete "\""
$array = string.split(/\\r/)
$array = string.split(/\\n/)

$array.map do |l|
  c = l.include? "#{characters}"
  counts += 1 if c == true
  next if c == true
end

def delete_all(characters)
  $array.each do |l|
  l.replace("") if l.include? characters
end
end

def puts_what(ct, l, c)
  if ct == 1 then puts "Did you mean #{l}?"
  else puts "#{c} exist in #{ct} lines. Do you want to delete all of them or just #{l}?" end
end

if string.include? "#{characters}"
  $array.each do |row|
  if row.include? "#{characters}" then puts_what(counts, row, characters)
    intent = gets.chomp()
    if intent == "yes"
      $array.delete row
      open_again = File.open(filename, 'w+')
      open_again.puts $array
      open_again.close()
      puts "#{row} deleted!"
      break
    elsif intent == "all"
      if counts == 1 then break end
      delete_all(characters)
      $array.delete ""
      open_once_more = File.open(filename, 'w+')
      open_once_more.puts $array
      open_once_more.close()
      puts "All the lines that contain #{characters} are deleted!"
      break
    elsif intent == "no" then puts "Never mind, then."
    end
  end
  end
else
  puts "Can't find #{characters}"
end
```

It works 100% perfectly! The only bad thing about this script is that it alway lefts a blank line at the end of the file, but if you have no problem wih that, you can use the script just fine.

P.S.: It uses inplace editing so it's not recommended for big files, it will eat your resources.

**P.P.S: My script is long and complicated, so if any of the advanced Ruby programmers wants to improve my script, he or she is welcome!**

Answer (score 0):

You will find that `sub('some text', '')` or you can use `sub` as well, depending on your needs, can be used to replace the found word or words with nil, effectively "deleting" it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your code on a UNIX flavor machine (Linux, Mac OS X) you can cheat and use a sed command in a system call.

```
puts "Enter media to delete";
characters = gets.chomp;

system("sed s/#{characters}// arraystarter.rb > output.rb")
```

If you need to run this in pure Ruby and have it be high performance, Google 'Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm' or look at this [example code](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Knuth-Morris-Pratt_Algorithm_Examples#Ruby)

If this is some kind of homework exercise, then neither of these suggestions are the way to go.